# Как запустить валидацию формы без ее отправки

Tags: javascript, html, валидация

Мне нужно запустить HTML 5 валидатор, но при этом не отправлять форму,
Нужно проверять значение поля по клику на btn-custom,
Если поле пустое сообщить пользователю, если поле заполенно тогда пропускать клик по кнопке

```
<div class="object_form">
  <label class="sr-only" for="form_object_size"></label>
  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form_object_size" placeholder="Площадь объекта" required>
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
      <button type="button" class="btn-custom">Узнать</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `HTML 5 валидатор`, `сообщить пользователю` - это как?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/HTML/HTML5/Constraint_validation

Answer (score 1):

Надо добавить форму и кнопку сабмит. Если форма не валидная, то сабмит происходить не будет и покажется сообщение об ошибке.

```js
object_form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
  console.log('submit');
});
```

```html
<form id="object_form" class="object_form">
  <label class="sr-only" for="form_object_size"></label>
  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="form_object_size" placeholder="Площадь объекта" required>
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
      <button type="submit" class="btn-custom">Узнать</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```